# SELECT statement to find SUM of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query statement that will find sum of the TaskLength column.

I've tried quite a number combinations placing the SQL `SUM` function in the query using comma separators, and `AND` statements. Without the `SUM TaskLength`, the query works fine.

This is being used in a `c# WPF` application but I'm able to test the query statements inside the Visual Studio, Server Explorer query window.

Here is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT TaskName, TaskLength FROM myTable, SUM TaskLength 
WHERE TaskName='Maintenance' AND EventStartTime 
BETWEEN '8/17/2019' AND '8/19/2019'
```

This is my table:

```
TABLE myTable 
ID    TaskName      EventStartTime          TaskLength
318   START SHIFT   8/17/2019 11:51:00 AM   16                  
319   Maintenance   8/17/2019 12:07:00 PM   10                  
320   Part Prep     8/17/2019 12:17:00 PM   13                  
321   Production    8/17/2019 12:30:00 PM   117                 
322   Part Prep     8/17/2019 02:26:00 PM   45                  
323   Downtime      8/17/2019 02:28:00 PM   65                  
327   START SHIFT   8/17/2019 03:48:00 PM   00                  
328   Maintenance   8/17/2019 03:48:00 PM   25                  
329   Part Prep     8/17/2019 03:48:00 PM   35                  
330   Production    8/17/2019 03:48:00 PM   120                 
331   START SHIFT   8/17/2019 03:59:00 PM   10                  
332   Maintenance   8/17/2019 03:59:00 PM   90
```

I am getting `Incorrect Syntax Near..` error. I expect when it works out correctly I will get a result of 125.

*Revised query with entire code block:*

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    string query = @"SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength) as TaskLength FROM myTable " +
          "WHERE EventStartTime BETWEEN '2019/8/17' AND '2019/8/19' GROUP BY TaskName";

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
      {
          con.Open();

          object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();  // returns 'Downtime'
          string totalMinutes = Convert.ToString(result);

      }
}
```

I'm progressing along. The code executes without errors except the result returns "Downtime" from the TaskName column instead of 125 from SUM(TaskLength) that I expect.

This query does work correctly in the Visual Studio SQL query window.

Comment: You need to read about sql syntax on how to use SUM and Group By to get your desired result

Comment: Sum is a function so you will need to use SUM(fieldname) and then also group by other fields that you are selecting that are not part of your aggregate operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, answer to this question is **`SUM ()`** and `Group by`, just want bring following points into consideration as I have not noticed in any answer:

1. Always use date format `yyyy-mm-dd` when you manually passing the values in filter or any other place in query, otherwise SQL engine might through error  `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` this would happen in case if the SQL Server environmental setup different than the format date that we used i.e. query format `MM-DD-YYYY` server environmental setup format `DD-MM-YYYY`.
2. When you do scalar functions or expressions (in our case `sum`), column label would be wiped-out, be sure to mentioned `as` with column label - *it is good practice, your query would work without alias*

```
SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength) as TaskLength
FROM myTable 
WHERE TaskName = 'Maintenance' AND
      EventStartTime between '2019-08-17' AND '2019-08-20'
GROUP BY TaskName
```

**Updated as per comment**

```
SELECT SUM(TaskLength) as TaskLength
FROM myTable 
WHERE TaskName = 'Maintenance' AND
      EventStartTime between '2019-08-17' AND '2019-08-20'
```

Comment: I revised the query and added the entire code block with the groups suggestions to my original post. I have been able to run the query without errors, However, the result I am getting is not the result of the SUM. Instead I am getting a TaskName result.  <br/>  @MPOST

Comment: That could because the query result having 2 columns, you are result get filled by first column, try updated query in my answer.

Comment: How would I be able to return both columns?

Answer (score 2):

`SUM` is a function so you will need to use `SUM(TaskLength)` and then also `GROUP BY` other fields that you are selecting that are not part of your aggregate operation.

Try querying the below:

```
Query = 
@"SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength)
 FROM myTable
 WHERE TaskName='Maintenance' AND EventStartTime
 BETWEEN '8/17/2019' AND '8/19/2019'
 GROUP BY TaskName"
```

Answer (score 2):

The summation is specified in the SUM() function in the `SELECT` clause, which requires a `GROUP BY` clause with all of the non-aggregated fields from the `SELECT` clause.

```
Query = @"SELECT TaskName, sum(TaskLength) as TotalTaskLength 
          FROM myTable
          WHERE TaskName='Maintenance' 
            AND EventStartTime BETWEEN '8/17/2019' AND '8/19/2019'
          GROUP BY TaskName"
```

Comment: With this I got the following exception: 
    string query = @"SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength) as TotalTaskLength 
    FROM myTable WHERE EventStartTime 
    BETWEEN '8/17/2019' AND '8/19/2019' 
    GROUP BY TaskLength";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column 'myTable.TaskName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I added TaskName to the GROUP BY and got an Operand data type char is invalid.  I believe that is because TaskLength is a string from a TimeSpan object. 

    string query = @"SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength) as TotalTaskLength 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE EventStartTime 
    BETWEEN '8/17/2019' AND '8/19/2019' 
    GROUP BY TaskName, TaskLength";

Comment: Sorry about the formatting... still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Group ONLY on TaskName.  In your first example, you used TaskLength instead of TaskName, and in the second, you used both.

Comment: The basic meaning is like this:   "Take all of rows and put them into buckets where each bucket consists of all rows with the same TaskName (that's the GROUP BY).  Within an individual bucket, you can reference the common fields directly, which in this case is TaskName, but for everything else, you need to specify a way to combine this bucket of rows into a single value.  In this case, you are using SUM(TaskLength).  There are many other aggregate functions, like COUNT(), AVG(), etc...  but the idea is to combine multiple rows into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that "08/17/2019" means "08/17/2019 00:00:00" and "08/19/2019" means "08/19/2019 00:00:00". You should use:
EvenStartTime >= "08/17/2019" and EventStartTime < dateadd(dd, 1, "08/19/2019") to get all the matching records.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer, FYI...  An answer specifically answers the question.  A comment gives advice on where to look, suggests for improving the nature of the question, etc...  You are correct in what you said, but it isn't a direct answer to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT TaskName, SUM(TaskLength)
FROM myTable 
WHERE TaskName = 'Maintenance' AND
      EventStartTime >= '2019-08-17' AND
      EventStartTime < '2019-08-20'
GROUP BY TaskName ;
```

Note the date comparisons.  First, the date values are in the format YYYY-MM-DD, which is the standard format for dates (in both SQL and ISO standards).  Second, it uses `>=` and `<`.  This is appropriate for both date and time comparisons and is safer than `BETWEEN`.